# How to move DevOps artifacts to Jfrog artifactory

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-container-registry

We have recently moved to Jfrog artifactory. We have few Nuget packages hosted on our azure DevOps artifacts. How to move these artifacts to Jfrog artifactory? I want to maintain all the version history as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution,

1. Downloaded the Nuget packages from DevOps
2. Uploaded the same packages to JFrog Artifacts

Comment: Using a remote repository may also be an option so that the artifacts are accessible during the migration